# HIbernate join a table, which is outside current join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, join

I'm just trying to join three tables.
These are my tables:

```
Account
acc_id

Account 2 Project
acc_id, proj_id

Project
proj_id

Topic
t_id, proj_id
```

My classes are

```
 Topic //(with a member Project project)
 Project
 Account //(with a member List<Project> assignedProjects)
```

Now I added a query to get the title of all `assignedProjects`, which works fine. I'm using a `createCriteria` and a `createAlias` to get the join going.

```
private void setProjectCriteria(Criteria criteria, AccountFilter accountFilter) {
    /*
    criteria.createCriteria("assignedProjects").createAlias("sponsor", "s").add(
            Restrictions.or(
                    Restrictions.like("title", "%" + accountFilter.getProject().getTitle() + "%"),
                    Restrictions.like("s.title", "%" + accountFilter.getProject().getTitle() + "%")));
    */

    Criterion criterion = null;
    for(Project project : accountFilter.getProjects()) {
        Criterion title = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("title", "%" + project.getTitle() + "%"),
                Restrictions.like("s.title", "%" + project.getTitle() + "%"));
                //Restrictions.like("t.title", "%" + project.getTitle() + "%"));
        if(criterion == null)
            criterion = title;
        criterion = Restrictions.or(criterion, title);
    }

    criteria.createCriteria("assignedProjects").createCriteria("topic").createAlias("sponsor", "s").add(criterion);
}
```

Now, however, I want to join the topics with the projects. Every project has only one topic.
So it's a one-to-one from the projects point of view.

I tried adding

```
criteria.createAlias("topic", "t")
```

but that gives me an error saying class Project has no member topic (which is correct, since not Project has a member topic, but Topic has member project). How can I add that criteria to my already existing join?

Comment: Information about what your entity classes look like might be helpful.

Comment: Oh right: https://www.refheap.com/107680